# Torque2D, Class vs Datablock

Tags: tilemap, data-structure, scripting, torque

I'm scripting my first game with Torque2D and have not fully understood the difference between "Class" and `Datablock`.

To me it seems like `Datablock` is similar to a struct in C/C++ or a Record in Pascal. If I create `Datablocks` with keyword **new**, are they instantiated in the same way as a "Class"?

I have a large `TileMap` and need to attach some information to each Tile. I was thinking to use a `Datablock`, as a struct, to attach this information to the tile's `CustomData` property.

The two questions are: What is a `Datablock` and should I use a `Datablock` or a "Class" for this tile information?

Comment: A datablock isn't really comparable to anything in a language - it's just a part of the Torque engine. If I remember correctly a datablock is shared across several instances of whatever type that datablock refers to. But since this is speculative and I don't understand Torque fully, I won't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Torque Script class is really not a class in terms of C++ classes. It is more or less a namespace grouping "class" member functions together.

```
function MyClass::MyFunction1(%param1)
{
  echo(%param1);
}

function MyClass::MyFunction2(%param1,%param2)
{
  echo(%param1 + %param2);
}
```

These two functions are in the same namespace aka Class, `MyClass`. We can call the functions as static members.

```
MyClass::Function1("Hello World"); // echo Hello World
MyClass::Function2(10,5);          // echo 15
```

Like in JavaScript, fields aka variables can be added to a collection of fields. But you can't add them to a static class. You must add them to an instance of the class.

There are two ways to get access to a "class" instance.

```
%MyObj = new ScriptObject();
```

`%MyObj` is a numeric integer value representing the instance handle. This handle can be used to access any members of the class. The second way is to create an object instead of an instance handle.

```
new ScriptObject(MyObj);
```

But why did we create a `scriptObject` instead of our `MyClass`?

You can't create classes that isn't defined and exposed in the Torque core (C++ source). All Torque classes are derived from the `SimObject` class and so are `ScriptObject` and it also defines some special fields.

```
%MyObj = new ScriptObject(MyObject)
{
  class = "MyClass";
};
```

Now we can call our functions from the handle because we told it to be class `MyClass`.

```
%MyObj.Function1("Hello World");
```

or from the object.

```
MyObject.Function1("Hello World");
```

Since `MyObject` isn't a variable, it shall not be accessed with the %

Well, not entierly true. Because we call it through its handle, the first parameter will always be the handle itself and is usually defined like this.

```
function MyClass::MyFunction1(%this,%param1)
{
  echo("Handle:" SPC %this SPC "Param:" SPC %param1);
}
```

The "instance" is passed in as the first parameter. It doesn't need to be called `%this`, but it has been the common practice to name it `%this`.

We can add fields as we please to this particular instance by just assigning values to it.

```
function MyClass::MyFunction1(%this,%param1)
{
  %this.Message = %param1;
}

function MyClass::MyFunction2(%this)
{
  echo("Handle:" SPC %this SPC "Param:" SPC %this.Message);
}
```

Okay so what are DataBlocks?

Let's say we have different configurations of `MyClass`. We can create a DataBlock for each configuration and then tell the instance to use it. All members of the DataBlock will be accessible fields in the instance.

```
datablock AudioProfile(audioName)
{
   filename = "~/data/sound/Audio.wav";
   description = "myaudioDescription";
   preload = false;
};
```

As for classes a `datablock` must be based on a predefined `datablock`. However, you can add new fields as you like to them.

```
datablock AudioProfile(MyAudioDatablock)
{
   filename = "~/data/sound/Audio.wav";
   description = "myaudioDescription";
   preload = false;
   Message = "My field";
};
```

Here we created a new `datablock` based on the `AudioProfile datablock` and added one extra field; Message.
We can now create our class and add all the fields from the `datablock` at once.

```
%MyObj = new ScriptObject()
{
  datablock = MyAudioDatablock;
  class = "MyClass";
};

%myObj.Function2(); // echo My field
```

If we have the same class but many different configurations, we can create one `datablock` for each configuration and assign them when we create the class instance.